# Vagarant vm installation issue

Tags: ubuntu, centos, vagrant, virtual-machine, vagrant-windows

I have installed vagrant in my system and wanted to install **ubuntu/jammy64** through vagrant but got the following error while installing

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'ubuntu/jammy64' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
```

`

How can I solve this issue and start VM

**Command used**
`1. vagrant init ubuntu/jammy64` { init was successful } 
`2. vagrant up`